# Django templates files

Tags: django, django-templates

Django template works fine with a `.html` file for me, and I have no issues with it.
I was just wondering if there were any means to use other files like `.php` for rendering.

Comment: I wouldn't call PHP an upgrade over Django!

Comment: I just edited the question. Please view.

Comment: Your question is still a bit vague. Do you want to use Django and PHP on the same server? If so, you use something like NGINX to send some paths to Django, and other paths to PHP. The two don't really plug together. What are you wanting to render?

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I was just being curious.